# can you fake *nix uptime?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, uptime

Just curious, Can you fake an `uptime`, for instance increase it to 10 years?

I have tried changing system time, and it won't do this trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this utility: [UptimeFaker](http://web.archive.org/web/20161025152929/http://etheus.net/UptimeFaker).

Answer (score 9):

```
alias uptime='echo " 11:07:17 up 10 BILLION YEARS!,  4 users,  load average: 0.38, 0.52, 0.41"'
```

If you want to get extra-fancy, you could take the actual uptime output and modify that.

Comment: thats one way, but is there a way to `/usr/bin/uptime` to produce this?

Comment: @c2h2: if you tell us what you're trying to achieve, then we might be able to find out what you want. Replacing `/usr/bin/uptime` with a shellscript would be one possible approach (people could still query `/proc/uptime` however).

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything harm, just curious if this is something can be manually changed. so next time when I login some machines and check uptime, I know no one has hacked anything.

Comment: @c2h2: how does the uptime tell you that nothing has been hacked?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you should be able to attach a gdb to the running kernel, and hack the uptime value. You'd need to know where it was kept, and have a symbols file. I am assuming here, that uptime is held in something statically allocated.

Alternatively, write a small kernel module which hacks the uptime when you load it (and immediately unloads again).

Comment: If it's statically allocated, you could also find it in `/dev/mem` and modify it directly.